# Modify data in LDAP server using Outlook or Thunderbird

Tags: outlook, ldap, thunderbird

both Outlook and Thunderbird are able to find contacts in a LDAP server, but none of them are able to modify contacts data.
Is there a plug-in or anything else to allow such thing?

Regards, Cédric

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any. But this guy seems to have managed doing it with VBScript which with some further work you should be able to nicely integrate into Outlook

[Add/Modify/Delete Exchange Contact with VBScript](http://phongdam.supersized.org/archives/2-AddModifyDelete-Exchange-Contact-with-VBScript.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't, even nowadays - late 2011 (TB is not supporting it, and also Outlook 2007). Anyhow, some mail clients are allowing this, in example Evolution.

I have not tested Outlook 2010, but i feel this is the same.

To check: if you can modify an ActiveDirectory directory. AD is LDAP, although the schema is specific to microsoft.